# How to transform embeded variables with optional indexing?

Tags: python

For an input text, I want to treat strings matching `#^[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]+` (e.g., `#var`) as variables and convert it to `<varname>[i]`, where `<varname>` is the part matching `[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]+`.

However, there can be also suffixes associated with varnames `#^[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]+.-?[0-9]+` (e.g, `#var.-3`, `#var.4`). For those, I want to transform them to things like `var[i-3]` and `var[i+4]`. Note that `#var.-3` takes a higher precedence than `#var`, meaning `#var.-3` should be matched first although `#var` can match whenever `#var.-3` can match.

How to make this text transform using python?

Example input:

```
print #var, #var2.-3, #var3.4
```

Example output:

```
print var[i], var2[i-3], var3[i+4]
```

When you run `./program.py <<< 'print #var, #var2.-3, #var3.4'` in command line, it should print `print var[i], var2[i-3], var3[i+4]`.

Comment: So if `var=[1,2,3]`, `i=1`, you expect `print(transform("#var"))` to print 2?

Comment: No. These are not python code. They are just texts. The input is text, and the output is text.